# I'm using vue(-router) to develop a hybrid app, how can I save some data in history state, so I can restore them when I back to previous pages?

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, vuex

In Android apps, when you start a new activity, the original activity is still in there, with all its internal data, so when you come back, it is the same as before.

How can I simulate this behaviour in my vue.js hybrid app? Is there some existing solution?

PS. I'm aware of vuex, but I think if I want to all the internal states of the pages in the history stack, then I must implement a stack-like structure by vuex myself. Is there some existing library can do this for me?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Wrapping `<router-view>` in `<keep-alive>` would get you expected results.

Or some custom baked solution, similar [vuex-router-sync](https://github.com/vuejs/vuex-router-sync) library to keep your page state in sync with the router.